# uidatepicker on uitextfield: How can I disable particular textfield keyboard and enable uidatepicker?

Tags: ios, iphone, uidatepicker

I'm using uidatepicker pop up while click in uitextfield, The date picker is poping up with keyboard and How can I disable particular textfield keyboard and enable uidatepicker?

[image: uidatepicker]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly set your textfield delegate if you have not already set it then in delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField isEqual:toDateTxtFld])
    {
        // Add this code in delegate
        [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];

        // ADD YOUR CODE FOR DATEPICKER Code

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

So keyboard will resign whenever you click in textfield.

Comment: i did den also first time keyboard is coming when i press return datepicker is coming

Answer (score 0):

If the date picker and the keyboard are popping up **together**, you can always call `[myTextField resignFirstResponder];` to remove the keyboard if it has popped up when the user tapped on the UITextField

Comment: where should i give this.i did in the textFieldShouldReturn but also first key board is coming and date pickr is coming

Comment: call [textField resignFirstResponder]; when you want the keyboard to disappear. To make it come back, call [textField becomeFirstResponder];